# Putting objects of the same class into a dictionary with different keys Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have these Objects:

```
class Object(object):

    def __init__(self, name, *parameters):
        self.name = name
        self.parameters = parameters

    def name(self):
        return self.name

    def parameters(self):
        return self.parameters

class Parameter(object):

    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
```

My aim is to get all parameters of 1 object in a dictionary, but it needs to end up like this:

```
{ParameterOne: "ValueOne", ParameterTwo: "ValueTwo"}
```

Since I have to be able to give the parameters different names, I can't do it like this:

```
class Parameter(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.ParameterOne = value
```

I tried it like this which obviously didn't work:

```
data = {}
    for parameter in object.parameters:
        data.update(vars(parameter))
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: `__dict__` on the object. `object.__dict__` should do it.

Comment: That returns something like

    {'name': 'CreatedObjectTwo', 'parameters': (<Parameter object at 0x7f248d846150>, <Parameter object at 0x7f248d846810>)}

Comment: Apologies. From your example I thought you wanted to be able to name them as in `self.ParameterOne`. What is it you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: My fault I didn't ask very clearly. But the edited answer I accepted is what I was trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = {parameter: ''.join(['Value ', str(index)]) 
         for index, parameter in enumerate(object.parameters)}
```

This will give you `{parameter0: 'Value 0', ...}`  If you want to get the English words for the numbers, you;ll have to either roll your own function for it or use an external package like `inflect`.

Just an observation, but most dictionaries would have the string mapping to the object, not the other way around.  Is there some reason you're doing it this way?

EDIT:

Rereading your question, are you looking for

```
data = {parameter: parameter.name for parameter in object.parameters}
```

I think you might want to try instead

```
data = {parameter.name: parameter.value for parameter in object.parameters}
```